# python for .net Module not found Error no module named Numpy

Tags: python, .net

I am trying to call Python functions from C# with Python.Runtime.
I have used this example from the internet.

When I try to run it , it says. no module named Numpy.
Numpy is working very well under Python.
Where am I going wrong?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
                dynamic sin = np.sin;
                Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));
                Console.WriteLine(sin(5));
                double c = np.cos(5) + sin(5);
                Console.WriteLine(c);
                 dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
                // dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, Py.kw("dtype", np.int32));
                 Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);
               //  Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);
               //  Console.WriteLine(a * b);
                dynamic pd = Py.Import("pandas");
                dynamic plt = Py.Import("matplotlib");
            }
                Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: this is the worst software I've ever used. I literally am boiling over this. Did you ever figure it out? I've added every damn path to every damn path variable. Just... doesn't work. It just doesn't work. Sure, it works if I use Py_Main, but then I get threading errors that don't exist in any other situation. Terrible documentation. Literally NO results on the the entire internet for using Python Runtime's .Exec method and "Module Not Found". Literally the worst library I've EVER used in 29 years of programming. Disgusting. No pride in their code, or testing obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it.

First try installing numpy using

```
$ pip install numpy
```

You probably have done this step, but still got the same error.

This is due to your pip and packages belonging to a different python installation than the one Python.Net is seeing. For example, on my Windows 10, I found at least 5 different Python inbstallation with python.exe and python39.dll files.

Solution outline:

1. remove or rename all other python39.dll files
2. (only for Windows) uninstall ANY Python installation that was done through Microsoft Store
3. make sure you install only one Python version from installer, not Microsoft Store. Make sure it is the same version as your Python.Net. 3.10 or above are not supported by Python.Net
4. add your Python and Pip locations to PATH
5. start a new command prompt (to pick up PATH change)
6. run pip install numpy (and any other package)

More info about what is happening, at least what was happening for me:

Python.Net is basically picking up the first python39.dll it finds using the system PATH. Exact name of the DLL it uses changes based on which version you have picked.

I used some process viewing program to list which DLLs were being loaded by my application when it was running and found out which Python39.dll it Python.Net was using. I used "Far Manager"s "Process Viewer" plugin for this purpose, but I am sure there are better programs for this.
I saw C:\AWSCLI2\python39.dll was the one being picked up (totally wrong place). I renamed this DLL and any other unwanted DLLs to python39.bak, leaving only my actual installation location DLL.

However, I also hit another issue specific to Windows 10 and Microsoft Store.
In Windows 10/11, you can install Python from the Microsoft Store, this is very easy, however it has issues compared to a manual install. Store version of Pyhton.exe and Python39.dll are not accessible by the user. For example, you cannot copy, rename or delete these files, you will get and access denied error. If this is your Python installation, Python.Net cannot load the python39.dll, and gives a "DLL not accessible" error at PythonEngine.Initialize().

Solution is to remove the Store version and download the installer from Python website and install from there. Be sure to add the Python.exe and Pip.exe locations (different folders) to your PATH and restart any program (e.g. Command Prompt and Visual Studio) before you retry.

I know this is a very old post, but since I couldn't find any answers to the same question even after this much time, I am assuming this answer will help some others.

Feel free to try the solution and comment. I am not a Python expert and probably don't know everything here.